# NFSv4 which "domain" to put in idmapd.conf?

Tags: linux, nfs, identity-map

I'm using NFSv4 but suddenly when the NFS Server got rebooted, all the files on the Clients are having `nobody` ownerships after the Server is booted and started its whatever services.

Then i found some solutions to set the `Domain=_____` in the `idmapd.conf` file.

- But what am i suppose to put there (in both Server and Clients)?
- I only have IP Addresses.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

This will be your NFSv4 domain, not necessarily related to your DNS domain. The NFSv4 server will deny access to clients which are not in the same domain.

Just pick whatever you think is suitable, and use it for both server and clients. Although it's unrelated to your DNS domain, that's probably a good choice to use for your NFSv4 domain.

Comment: So its like Passwords/ Keys, huh?